# Transfer between Dubai's Terminals 3 and 1 when travelling on separate tickets and bags recheck in?

Tags: transit-visas, dubai

I arrive in Dubai at terminal 3 and have an onward flight from terminal 1 on Aeroflot Airlines to Moscow. Also, I need to self transfer my checked in bags from terminal 3 to terminal 1. My layover at the airport is 6hrs.

I was told by Marhaba airpot services that to collect bags from terminal 3, I would have to go through UAE immigration department which will require a **transit visa**. However, when I called Emirates airlines, they told that **no visa** would be required since I am not stepping out of the airport.

I am confused now. Can anyone please help me if a transit visa or any other visa is required for the bags transfer?

Comment: What is your citizenship? https://government.ae/en/information-and-services/visiting-and-exploring-the-uae/transit-visa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marhaba was correct in that you do need to pass immigration to collect your luggage and transfer it to your onward flight when you have separate tickets. However, Marhaba themselves can go landside and transfer the bags to your next flight for you, so that you do not need to pass immigration yourself. They do charge a fee for this service. Stop at the Marhaba desk after you arrive in Dubai.

Comment: Or probably better, book the service in advance on their website.